# React sever keeps experiencing connection error with socket.io (When re-opening project)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

I'm a game programmer that has been learning some React and JavaScript. So, there may be quite a few knowledge gaps and is why I'm posting a GitHub repo.

I've been working on a web chat app using `Socket.io` and keep experiencing a connection error. I've been following along with this tutorial: https://youtu.be/84GXJANOYFw

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

GET http://192.168.1.2:3231/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MHOpBCx 0 ()  polling-xhr.js:263
```

Code: https://github.com/sujaygchand/react-web-chat-app-2

I believe that the `src/server/SocketManager.js` has an issue. However, I log to console in `src/components/Layout.js:33` and discovered it was a console error.

The one thing that I do not understand is that `socket.io` runs perfectly. When, I make a new project; it always connect. But, whenever I shutdown my computer and reopen the files it always throws this error. This has happened to every project that I've used `socket.io` on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, turns out I don't have a static IP. So, I have to change the socketUrl. Whenever, I restart my computer.